# Power-BI: How can I calculate a measure which contains a variable for a monthly prognoses?

Tags: powerbi

I have a Table with

- Customer
- First Investment
- Last Investment
- Number of contracts

I want to calculate the buying probability for the future (NBD / Pareto Model):

(First Investment - Last Investment) / (First Investment - **TODAY**)

I want to calculate this buying probability for sequential months (for each month in the next twelve months). Therefore **Today** should by dynamic.

(First Investment - Last Investment) / (First Investment - (**TODAY** + Variable))

Variable:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
...

I am looking for the approach how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to create a scenario for you; but I haven't tested it. All you need is to create a date column showing today's date(maybe create a date table consisting of only (1Column*1Row) equal to today's date; because you need a date column reference in the formula.

```
VAR Buying_Prob = 
DIVIDE(
(First Investment - Last Investment), (First Investment -[Date])
VAR Period_Number = 1 --- 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 whatever
VAR Result = 
DIVIDE(
(First Investment - Last Investment), (First Investment - (DATEADD([Date], Period_Number ,MONTH)
)
RETURN Result
```

Comment: Thank you! Understand. Is this the correct syntax to populate a variable with different values?
VAR Period_Number = 1 --- 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Comment: @Hello Florian, The answer to your question is "no". You will just need to put in any one of numbers. If you want 2 months from today() , It will be : VAR Period_Number = 2 . unfortunately, There is no iteration logic in Power BI like in Python (for number in list: Period_Number = number Print(Period_Number)) The best part here is when you decide to change Period_Number , you can do it only in variable part, and every reference to it inside your code will automatically change. Variables are very important in BI, and are considered as one of the best BI practices.

Comment: Hey Ozan, thanx. Thats what I am looking for (the list-function).

Comment: @Florian Then You decided to solve the problem with Power Query(M-Code List Function) which is not DAX ; but worth the effort . That's great. 